# Преобразование массива байтов в строку с заданной кодировкой

Tags: java

В буфер `mes` приходит сообщение в виде байтов.
Как это сообщение из буфера записать в строку с кодировкой "ASCII"?

```
byte[] mes = new byte[10];
DI = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
int resive = DI.read(mes);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стоит отметить то, что сообщение должно содержать только 10 символов, а не больше т.к им просто нет места в массиве. 
Для того, чтобы из массива получить строку надо:

```
String a = new String(mes, "ASCII");
```

Кодировку можно использовать и другую, например "UTF-8".

Comment: небольшое дополнение - лучше использовать StandardCharsets чем писать самому название кодировок, есть шанс промахнуться и ошибиться.

Comment: Да, действительно работает. Благодарю за оперативность